# Can I change my clothes or am I stuck in this horrible grey-and-purple suit?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

I'd downloaded the Saint's Row the Third Initiation Station to fool around with. What can I say, I like playing dress-up. I'd made a few characters but never uploaded them to the community site. Figured I'd wait for the game to arrive and just play from there.

Fast-forward to today, and after making my character, I'm looking around the menus and can not find the clothing section for the life of me. I find it hard to believe that the ability to change clothing is solely available from an external program. What am I missing here?

Comment: Hey, that's Saints' purple! You're not dissing the colors, are you?

Comment: @Dave DuPlantis No, no, no... It's not the grey-and-purple part so much as the *suit*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only mess around with extended clothing options in the Initiation Station before the start of the game. If you decide not to download a character from the website that had these options available, you won't be able to change your clothes or do further customization like tattoos until you head to the relevant store ingame.

- You can purchase new clothes at **Planet Saints**, **Leather & Lace**, and **Let's Pretend**
- You can purchase new tattoos at **Rusty's Needle**
- You can purchase new piercings at **Nobody Loves Me** (as well as a small selection of clothing)
- You can adjust your character's base appearance (gender/body/face/hair/etc.) at **Image As Designed**

Comment: In fact, in one of the early story missions you will be taken to a Planet Saints and asked to change your clothes in order to continue.

Comment: @agent86 I just hit that mission. It was a *HUGE* "duh!" moment for me... I really should have known that. lol